# How to add border radius on table row

Tags: css

Does anyone know how to style tr as we like?

I've used border-collapse on table, after that tr's can display 1px solid border I give them.

However, when I've tried `-moz-border-radius`, it doesn't work. Even simple margin doesn't work.

Answer (score 354, accepted):

You can only apply border-radius to td, not tr or table.  I've gotten around this for rounded corner tables by using these styles:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-style: none solid solid none;
  padding: 10px;
}

tr:first-child td:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 10px; }
tr:first-child td:last-child { border-top-right-radius: 10px; }

tr:last-child td:first-child { border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; }
tr:last-child td:last-child { border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; }

tr:first-child td { border-top-style: solid; }
tr td:first-child { border-left-style: solid; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>1.2</td>
    <td>1.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td>2.2</td>
    <td>2.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.1</td>
    <td>3.2</td>
    <td>3.3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Be sure to provide all the vendor prefixes. You can see it in action on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/theazureshadow/LRKXD/1/) too.

Comment: Right.  If you want rounded corners in IE, you're going to have to use images and strange markup.

Comment: @Henson: No it won't because CSS3 isn't supported in IE<9 however, you can use CSS3PIE to make it work in IE including IE6: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: Warning: if you omit `border-collapse: separate;` then this won't work.

Comment: @KevinBorders that is incorrect, at least in Chrome v39. I did have a problem getting this to work when I had background-color applied to the table itself. Apparently it must be on the tr or td elements.

Comment: @Koveras that must be a browser-specific requirement then. Not sure which browsers work without the border-collapse, but it is needed for full compatibility.

Comment: `separate` is needed for Chrome 44.

Comment: Very usefull, perfect to my case. Was a very simple solution, but i needed to put border at the left borders of my first and end <td>  <code>table tr td:first-child { 
   border-top-left-radius: 10px;
   border-left-width:10px; 
   border-bottom-left-radius: 10px
  }
  
  table tr td:last-child { 
   border-top-right-radius: 10px;
   border-right-width:10px; 
   border-bottom-right-radius: 10px
  } </code>

Comment: @KevinBorders nomen est omen

Answer (score 95):

### Actual Spacing Between Rows

This is an old thread, but I noticed reading the comments from the OP on other answers that the original goal was apparently to have `border-radius` on the rows, and gaps *between* the rows. It does not appear that the current solutions exactly do that. theazureshadow's answer is headed in the right direction, but seems to need a bit more.

For those interested in such, [here is a fiddle that does separate the rows and applies the radius to each row.](http://jsfiddle.net/LRKXD/717/) (NOTE: [Firefox currently has a bug in displaying/clipping `background-color` at the border radii](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=921341).)

The code is as follows (and as theazureshadow noted, for earlier browser support, the various vendor prefixes for `border-radius` need added).

```
table { 
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border-spacing: 0 10px; 
    margin-top: -10px; /* correct offset on first border spacing if desired */
}
td {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-style: solid none;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: cyan;
}
td:first-child {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
td:last-child {
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 10px; 
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Bonus info: `border-radius` has no effect on tables with `border-collapse: collapse;` and border set on `td`'s. And it doesn't matter if `border-radius` is set on `table`, `tr` or `td`—it's ignored.

http://jsfiddle.net/Exe3g/

Comment: The jsfiddle has rounded corners on Firefox.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yes, if border-collapse: collapse; is not set, click the toggle button and see magic happen.

Comment: "border-radius has no effect on tables with border-collapse: collapse;" was helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The tr element does honor the border-radius. Can use pure html and css, no javascript.

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/pflies/zL08hqp1/10/

```css
tr {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
}
.solid {
    border: 2px red solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.dotted {
    border: 2px green dotted;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.dashed {
    border: 2px blue dashed;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>06</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='dotted'>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>09</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='solid'>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='dotted'>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='dashed'>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Changing the TR's display property to "block" will most likely mess up the layout of the table. In particular, if your table has multiple rows containing various content lengths, the table cells will not align up.

Comment: @Jess is right. It only works with `display: block`, as a side effect, the row alignment will be broken if it contains various length.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use outline:

```css
table {
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [Opera](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/findpost.pl?id=12117122) the CSS3 standard does not define the use of `border-radius` on TDs.  My experience is that Firefox and Chrome support it but Opera does not (don't know about IE). The workaround is to wrap the td content in a div and then apply the `border-radius` to the div.

Answer (score 3):

Not trying to take any credits here, all credit goes to @theazureshadow for his reply, but I personally had to adapt it for a table that has some `<th>` instead of `<td>` for it's first row's cells.

I'm just posting the modified version here in case some of you want to use @theazureshadow's solution, but like me, have some `<th>` in the first `<tr>`. The class "reportTable" only have to be applied to the table itself.:

```
table.reportTable {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table.reportTable td {
    border: solid gray 1px;
    border-style: solid none none solid;
    padding: 10px;
}

table.reportTable td:last-child {
    border-right: solid gray 1px;
}

table.reportTable tr:last-child td{
    border-bottom: solid gray 1px;
}

table.reportTable th{
    border: solid gray 1px;
    border-style: solid none none solid;
    padding: 10px;
}

table.reportTable th:last-child{
    border-right: solid gray 1px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

table.reportTable th:first-child{
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

table.reportTable tr:last-child td:first-child{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}   

table.reportTable tr:last-child td:last-child{
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Feel free to adjust the paddings, radiuses, etc to fit your needs. Hope that helps people!

Answer (score 2):

I think collapsing your borders is the wrong thing to do in this case. Collapsing them basically means that the border between two neighboring cells becomes shared. This means it's unclear as to which direction it should curve given a radius.

Instead, you can give a border radius to the two lefthand corners of the first TD and the two righthand corners of the last one. You can use `first-child` and `last-child` selectors as suggested by theazureshadow, but these may be poorly supported by older versions of IE. It might be easier to just define classes, such as `.first-column` and `.last-column` to serve this purpose.

Comment: I collapse the border so the tr can display the style I give. I'll try the class method. but what about margin? i tried using border-spacing to display margins between rows, but that isn't the best way to do that, I believe....

Comment: There can be no margins between the rows if they share a border - that is when the border is collapsed. I am assuming what you're trying to do is get your TRs to have a background color with rounded corners? If so, un-collapsing them should work

Comment: actually the more pressing matter is to display margin between rows with borders. The border doesn't necessarily have to have rounded corners though

Answer (score 2):

All the answers are way too long. The easiest way to add border radius to a table element that accepts border as a property, is doing border radius with overflow: hidden.

```
border: xStyle xColor xSize;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-radius: 1em;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: @ypresto the top answer from #theazureshadow mentions that border radius does not work for tr, but the reason for that is because you cant even apply a border to it, but table does work :( I dont know why but that answer is from 2013.

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
tr:first-child th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 70px;
}

tr:first-child th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 70px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to @Craigo answer, I make some minor change, take a look:)

```css
      table {
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0 16px;
      }

      tr td {
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        transition: all ease 0.3s;
        padding: 5px;
      }

      tr td:first-child {
        border-right: 0px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
      }

      tr td:last-child {
        border-left: 0px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
      }

      tr td:not(:first-child, :last-child) {
        border-left: 0px;
        border-right: 0px;
      }

      tr:hover td:first-child {
        border-color: black;
        border-right: 0px;
      }

      tr:hover td:last-child {
        border-color: black;
        border-left: 0px;
      }

      tr:hover td:not(:first-child, :last-child) {
        border-color: black;
        border-left: 0px;
        border-right: 0px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>How to add border radius on table row</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>01</td>
          <td>02</td>
          <td>03</td>
          <td>04</td>
          <td>05</td>
          <td>06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>07</td>
          <td>08</td>
          <td>09</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding border-radius to tables, trs, and tds does not seem to work 100% in the latest versions of Chrome, FF, and IE.  What I do instead is, I wrap the table with a div and put the border-radius on it.

```
<div class="tableWrapper">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Content</td></tr>
  <table>
</div>

.tableWrapper {
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

If your table is not `width: 100%`, you can make your wrapper `float: left`, just remember to clear it.

Answer (score 1):

Or use box-shadow if table have collapse

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use border-collapse:seperate; and border-spacing:0; but only use border-right and border-bottom for the tds, with border-top applied to th and border-left applied to only tr td:nth-child(1).

You can then apply border radius to the corner tds (using nth-child to find them)

https://jsfiddle.net/j4wm1f29/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>title 1</th>
    <th>title 2</th>
    <th>title 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item 1</td>
    <td>item 2</td>
    <td>item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item 1</td>
    <td>item 2</td>
    <td>item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item 1</td>
    <td>item 2</td>
    <td>item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item 1</td>
    <td>item 2</td>
    <td>item 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
table {
  border-collapse: seperate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

tr th,
tr td {
  padding: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

tr th {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

tr td:nth-child(1),
tr th:nth-child(1) {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

/* border radius */
tr th:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}

tr th:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}

tr:nth-last-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}

tr:nth-last-child(1) td:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add `border-radius` in `tr` so you must put it in the first `td` and in the last `td`

In the first `td` you put borders only on the left side and in the last one you put them on the right side

Just do the following

```
tr td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

tr td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please add more details – ideally a running code snippet to illustrate your approach.

Answer (score 1):

While `table-row` display types (i.e. `<tr>`) don't support `border-radius` you can use `clip-path` with `xywh()` on most browsers starting in 2024.

```css
table tr {
  clip-path: xywh(0 0 100% 100% round 0.5em);
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape/xywh for more details on usage and browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that puts a border with radius on a single row:

```css
table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0; }

td { padding: 5px; }

.rowBorderStart {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.rowBorderMiddle {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
}

.rowBorderEnd {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td><td>1.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='rowBorderStart'>2.1</td><td class='rowBorderMiddle'>2.2</td><td class='rowBorderEnd'>2.3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3.1</td><td>3.2</td><td>3.3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to round the corners of the table:

```
thead th:first-child{border-top-right-radius: 15px;}

thead th:last-child{border-top-left-radius: 15px;}

tbody tr:last-child>td:first-child{border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;}

tbody tr:last-child>td:last-child{border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would Suggest you use .less instead,
change your .css file to .less and use the following code:

```
table { 
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0; 
}
td {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-style: none solid solid none;
    padding: 10px;
}
tr td:first-child { 
  border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
tr td:last-child { 
  border-top-right-radius: 10px; 
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
tr td { 
  border-top-style: solid; 
}
tr td:first-child { 
  border-left-style: solid; 
}

tr{
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr:hover{
  td{
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```