# Border Radius for each row in a table

Tags: html, css

I am having the table like this and I want to apply style to each row with rounded corner.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Month</td>
    <td>Savings</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I have written the CSS like this.

```
td
{
border-radius:5px;
border:2px solid red;
}
```

I am having multiple columns and I want to show the rows in a rounded corner. When I am trying this for a single cell, I can able to achieve.  Anyone help me.

Thanks in advance,
Karthick

Actually I want the output like this but there is a gap between each cell in a row. I tried using cell spacing but I cant get.

`````````````````````
td { border: solid 1px #000; }
tr td:first-child
{ 
  border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-right:none;
}
tr td:last-child 
{ 
border-top-right-radius: 10px; 
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-left:none;
}

/````````````````````\
\..................../
/````````````````````\
\..................../
/````````````````````\
\..................../
`````````````````````

My rows want to display like this with solid borders.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094126/border-radius-on-tr

Comment: @Timmerz: Those answers were for giving rounded corner and about cross browser compatibility. I didn't get my expected answers there. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

you can write like this:

```
td:first-child{
    -moz-border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
}
td:last-child{
    -moz-border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
}
td{background:red;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/RNWwu/1/

Comment: When I am trying this I cant give space between the rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
tr {
    border-radius:5px;
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

Change one letter, `d`, to `r` (`td` to `tr`).

Edit: Sorry, you can't apply border to tr. Try this 'hack' instead, borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094126/border-radius-on-tr):

```
table { border-collapse: separate; }
td { border: solid 1px #000; }
tr:first-child td:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 10px; }
tr:first-child td:last-child { border-top-left-radius: 10px; }
tr:last-child td:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 10px; }
tr:last-child td:last-child { border-top-left-radius: 10px; }
```

Comment: If you give tr then the whole border will break.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: In this there will be a small gab between each cell in a row.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: Actually I want the UI like this.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville it's just a suggestion never give an answer in such hurry if you didn't have confident that it's right.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this...however, you should just use `<div>` instead of `<table>`

```
<style>

table
{
border-collapse:separate;
border-spacing:1px;
}

td
{
background-color:red;
}

td:first-child
{
border-top-left-radius:5px;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
border:2px solid red;
}

td:last-child
{
border-top-right-radius:5px;
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
border:2px solid red;
}


</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Month</td>
    <td>Savings</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you should be using a div with rounded corners. tables don't support this very well.

Comment: This is an auto generated table by an agent. I cant use any DIV stuff there. And also lot of jQuery selectors acting on that table. The only way for me is to apply CSS. Any help...?

Comment: Only for UI nothing else... Its Makes 1 UI theme. Each row is a record. Showing them as a bar with a rounded corner.