# Table row border-radius doesn't work- alternative?

Tags: html, css, row, css-tables

If you look on my website here: http://mcderp.x10.mx/members.php, when hovering over the bottom row, you can see that the row doesn't have rounded corners, I've tried applying 'overflow: hidden' to the table class which does have rounded corners, but this doesn't work! :(

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100169/border-radius-for-each-row-in-a-table

Comment: Sorry Bram, didn't see that one :/ I'm using Firefox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Border Radius for each row in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100169/border-radius-for-each-row-in-a-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to style individual cells. Working example on Firefox and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/AyKE7/

CSS

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
    padding: 4px 7px;
}
/* hover */
tr:hover th,
tr:hover td {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
/* hover, left cell */
tr:hover th {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
/* hover, last cell on he right */
tr:hover td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the inspector, you have only declared one version, you need to add the vendor prefixes. it works fine in chrome

```
.myClass
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Unprefixed `border-radius` is widely supported, unless you want to support old browsers like FF 3.6 or Safari 4..

Comment: Cheers, didn't think that would be the problem, seeing as border-radius works everywhere else on the website :')

Comment: @RobW ok, because it wasn't working for him, he maybe had an older version of a browser

Comment: Wait, no, I've confused myself, I've applied no border-radius to the row tag, but I have to the table class, but the table has rounded corners in firefox, so I don't see why it's happening.. unless it's a problem with overflow?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this sample - this will help to fix the CSS issue. 
This CSS will work in Firefox, Safari/Chrome, Opera and even IE9 browser.

```
.bottomRow {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50px; border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 50px; border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
}
```