# css border-radius not working when applied to rows

Tags: css

I'm simply trying to put a border-radius around my table rows. I'm currently using jQuery Mobiles as the framework. Here is the code I'm using:

```
.ui-table tr {
    border: 5px solid rgb(51,51,51);
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

Now when I make it td it makes my columns have rounded edges. But when I make it tr for some reason the style doesn't take effect. I'm really not sure why

Comment: Ain't it a duplicate of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094126/border-radius-on-tr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100169/border-radius-for-each-row-in-a-table ?

Comment: Many apologizes, thanks for the link

Comment: border won't work for tr tag, use td instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the borders on `tr` tag you should use `table{border-collapse: collapse;}` and to display the radius you could use `display: block;` to `tr` tag.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jv45G/)

Answer (score 1):

for border to the table and tr here is the code just put into css file it will definitely work

```
table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr{
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
table, td, th
{
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  .ui-table tr {
    border: 5px solid rgb(51,51,51);
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to point it to `td`

```
.ui-table tr td
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/uDAnUKaL/2/)**