# Why I can't modify border in TableRow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, border

I'm trying to modify the border of a table row with border-radius but it doesn't work!
Here is my code:

```
function generateTableAntipasti() {
//Build an array containing Customer records.
var antipasti = new Array();
antipasti.push(["Antipasti"]);
antipasti.push(["Patatine"]);
antipasti.push(["Kellogs"]);
antipasti.push(["Ciao"]);
antipasti.push(["Hello"]);
antipasti.push(["Bye"]);

//Create a HTML Table element.
var table = document.createElement("Table");
table.border = "1";
table.className = "Antipasti";
table.cellSpacing = 20;

//Add the data rows.
for (var i = 0; i < antipasti.length; i++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = antipasti[i];
}

var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
dvTable.innerHTML = "";
dvTable.appendChild(table);
}
```

this is the code for JAVASCRIPT

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    border: 0px;
}

tr {
    width: 80%;
    height: 120px;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-color: orange;
    border-radius: 20px;

    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 4px #707070;
}

table tr td {
    color: black;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

this is the code for CSS

This is the image of the site.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vo52.png)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Check this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094126/how-to-add-border-radius-on-table-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094126/how-to-add-border-radius-on-table-row)

Comment: You could try `setAttribute()` or chage the border with the `.style` properties

Comment: @RobMoll thank you so much!