# Vuetify table same width on all cells

Tags: css, sass, vuetify.js

I would like to replicate the same design as in this screenshot:

[image: mock up]

I have been able to replicate some of this design styling the vuetify data table with the following CSS:

```
.v-data-table {
  @extend .elevation-0;

  .v-data-table__wrapper {
    table {

      td,
      th {
        padding-left: 16px !important;
        min-width: 170px !important;
        border: 1px solid #e8e8e8 !important;
        border-bottom: none !important;
        font: 14px/40px !important;
        text-align: left !important;
      }

      td {
        color: #666 !important;
      }

      tr {
        display: block !important;
      }

      th {
        color: #333 !important;
      }

      tbody {
        tr {
          @include radius(xl);
          @include elevation(4, true);
          margin: 20px 5px;
          background-color: #fbfbfb !important;
          cursor: pointer !important;
        }
      }

      thead.v-data-table-header tr {

        th {
          color: #818087 !important;
          box-shadow: none !important;
          border: none !important;
          border-bottom: none !important;
        }
      }

      tbody tr td {
        border: none !important;
        height: 65px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only problem I'm facing is that some of the rows are not alligned with the values of each cell:

[image: current table]

As you can see the current table doesn't have the `Plans` header alligned with it's values. If the usere have more than one activity group the cell takes up too much space.

You can check out a minimum reproducible problem here: https://codepen.io/teresakk/pen/MWyXaWv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with the help from another answer on stackoverflow:
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/16971333/4581336)

```
table {
      border-collapse: separate;
      border-spacing: 0 10px;
      margin-top: -10px; /* correct offset on first border spacing if desired */
    }

    th {
      background-color: map-get($grey, 'lighten-5') !important;
      border: none !important;
      box-shadow: none !important;
    }

    td {
      border: solid 1px transparent;
      border-style: solid none;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: map-get($shades, 'white');
      height: 60px !important;
    }

    td:first-child {
      border-left-style: solid;
      border-top-left-radius: 10px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    }

    td:last-child {
      border-right-style: solid;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
      border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    }
```