# Border radius is not applied . I try to apply border radius on tr tag but it's not working

Tags: html, css

Border radius is not applied. I try to apply border-radius on tr tag but it's not working

```
    <table  align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="80%"  >
        <h2>Let the borders collapse</h2>
    <tr class="border">
        <th class="side">Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th class="side">Lastname</th>
    </tr>
 
    </table>
    

  </td></tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p4wm06kg/3/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add border radius on table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094126/how-to-add-border-radius-on-table-row)

Comment: No it's a little bit requirement . I tried this one on my code but it's not fulfill my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codepen.io/turbo_baguettes/pen/gOmzGNN

works fine for me

```css
.border {
  /* margin: auto;  */
  border-style: hidden;
  border-spacing: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  border-collapse: separate !important;
  /* border-spacing: 0; */
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  /* -webkit-border-radius: 6px; */
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* border-right: none;
            border-left: none; */
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  
  /* TR BORDER HERE */
  border: 5px solid pink;
}
```

Comment: Please apply border-radius in pink color

Comment: Any Update on it ? 
Can you please apply border radius at outside .

Comment: sorry for not answering! at first I misunderstood the question, if you still need the answer, I found the solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094126/how-to-add-border-radius-on-table-row

Comment: Thanks Kacper kwinta !! Let me try to implement on my code