# Primeng p-table border radius not applying

Tags: css, primeng, angular11, primeng-table, p-table

I'am able to apply border to p-table using tableStyleClass but not border-radius. Any idea why?

```html
<p-table [value]="[0]" tableStyleClass="tableBorder"></p-table>
```

```css
.tableBorder{ border: 1.7px solid #dcdadad6; border-radius: 7px !important; }
```

Comment: What's in the Dev Inspector of the browser? Do you see your styles there? Any other styles?

Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094126/how-to-add-border-radius-on-table-row