# Round borders with DT datatables in R

Tags: javascript, css, r, datatables

I would like round borders on my DT table. Unfortunately my JS skills are very limited (or even inexistent) thus I would be very happy if somebody could help me to figure out how to implement round borders on a DT table in R.

This is my code so far:

```
DT::datatable(
  data = iris,
  options = list(
    initComplete = DT::JS(
      "function(settings, json) {",
      paste0(
        "$(this.api().table().header()).css({
          'background-color': 'black',
          'color': 'white',
          'border-top-left-radius': '4px',
          'border-top-right-radius': '4px'
          });"
      ),
      "}"
    )
  )
)
```

The last part `border-top-left-radius` does not work but something like this would be the solution. I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094126/how-to-add-border-radius-on-table-row) has the solution in pure JS but I need somebody to help me to implement this snippet in my R code.

Here is a screenshot from my code. Now I would like to have the top left and right border with a radius. As you can see the border is 90 degrees at the moment.

[image: still with pointy borders]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does the trick! Got the solution from the following [link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32790/rounded-corners-in-table-body-still-show-row-background-color-in-firefox) from datatables forum.

```
DT::datatable(
  data = iris,
  options = list(
    initComplete = DT::JS(
      "function(settings, json) {",
      "$('th').css({'background-color': 'black'});",
      "$('th').css({'color': 'white'});",
      "$('th:first-child').css({'border-top-left-radius': '15px'});",
      "$('th:last-child').css({'border-top-right-radius': '15px'});",
      "}"
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `overflow: hidden`.

```
DT::datatable(
  data = iris,
  options = list(
    initComplete = DT::JS(
      "function(settings, json) {",
      paste0(
        "$(this.api().table().header()).css({
          'background-color': 'black',
          'color': 'white',
          'border-top-left-radius': '4px',
          'border-top-right-radius': '4px', 
          'overflow': 'hidden'
          });"
      ),
      "}"
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Maybe my question was not that clear: The goal would be that the black header has round borders on the top left and right. With your code I am getting neither when I run it. Could you help with this additional information?

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again! But the border are still at 90 degrees and thus pointy. I added a screenshot. Does your code give you a different table than in my screen shot?