# How to add a border radius to a table row element using tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want my rows to have border radius but it doesn't work , I want it to look like this [image: as shown here]

I have space between rows by adding an empty tr with this css :

```
.spacer {
  height: 15px;
  background: transparent;
}
```

my table code looks like this :

```
 <table className="text-gray-500  rtl w-full  text-center font-inter text-base font-semibold ">
          <thead className="bg-white  text-base    text-primary">
            <tr>
              <td scope="col" className="px-4 py-6">
                الرقم
              </td>
              <td scope="col" className="px-4 py-6">
                اسم المشروع
              </td>
              <td scope="col" className="px-4 py-6">
                الحالة
              </td>
              <td scope="col" className="px-4 py-6">
                الدرجة
              </td>
              <td scope="col" className="px-4 py-6">
                التاريخ
              </td>
              <td scope="col" className="px-4 py-6">
                التعديل
              </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094126/2518285) about regular CSS, and [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16971333/2518285) most applicable to your situation. All you’ll have to do is to translate this technique into Tailwind.